# Can multiple clients can download the same file using FTP without performace impact?

Tags: ftp

I have a file at location "A" which will be downloaded by multiple clients via FTP. The clients can access the file at the same time. The host server (where file is stored) is solaris server with link speed of 100BT. The clients can support up to 1Gbps. Size of the file is nearly ~700 mb

When 5 to 6 clients downloaded the file, the download took around 20 mins. But when the number of clients was increased to ~40, the download took more than a hour.

My question here is that when the number of clients is increased will it have an impact on download speed? If yes then what are the factors that are responsible for this impact? Please clarify...

Comment: Total bandwidth on the server side is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a load of sections of pipe of varying thicknesses joined together with your server at one end and your client(s) at the other. The pieces of pipe here are:

1. the disk where your file is stored on the server
2. the CPU and memory bandwidth on your server
3. the network connection from your server (and all switches and hubs on the way)
4. the CPU and memory bandwidth on your client
5. the disk where the file will be saved on your client

Basically, the transfer is going to go as fast as the thinnest piece of pipe allows data to flow through it. As a rough guide, the performances will be

1. 60-150 MBytes/s
2. several GBytes/s
3. 100 Mbits/s or around 10-12 MBytes/s
4. several GBytes/s
5. 60-150 MBytes/s

As you can see, the server's 100Mb/s network interface is the biggest bottleneck by a massive factor (5-15x). Also, you say your file is 700mb (millibits), but I suspect you mean 700MB (megabytes). So, if your server's network interface is only 100 Mb/s (or 10MB/s) the 700MB file is going to take at least 70s to pass through the network and it will need to do so once for each client, so 5 clients are going to take at least 350s assuming no overheads.

Short answer:

1. try compressing the file,
2. or going on eBay to get a faster network interface for the server
3. distribute from the server to one (or more) of your 1Gb/s clients and then from there to other clients.

Answer (score 2):

This question would better be asked on superuser because it is not about programming.

But if your server has a 100 BT link, it can support about 10 MB / sec. Distribute this over 5 clients and each gets 2 MB/sec. Use 40 clients and each gets 250 KB/sec. Of course it gets slower the more clients you have.